# C# says "The port is already opened." Fixing it, then "The port is closed." What is wrong with my code?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I'm trying to put a Serial DataReceivedListener to automate the reading of data from the serial port. Before adding this event, everything works fine.

Certain commands cannot continue because C# complains that "The port is already opened." If I comment out "port.Open();", C# then complains that "The port is closed."

Here is the code that I think is covered by this whole thing.

```
    SerialPort port;

    String buffer;
    String[] bufferArray;
    String tellArduino;   // any random one-byte character to "ping" Arduino for a data point

    Queue<String> date = new Queue<String>();
    Queue<String> time = new Queue<String>();
    Queue<double> dcGen = new Queue<double>();


public Form1()
    {
        //
        //  IDE created this thing
        //
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        getDataPoint();
    }

    private void selectPort()
    {
        //
        //  Creates new instance of SerialPort with the same
        //  settings as that of the Arduino. Checks if the selected
        //  port can be opened. Catches common exceptions found while debugging
        //

        try
        {
            port = new SerialPort((string)ports.SelectedItem);
            port.BaudRate = 9600;
            port.Parity = Parity.None;
            port.StopBits = StopBits.One;


            port.Open();        // check if port can be opened
            port.Close();

            portUsedLabel.Text = (string)ports.SelectedItem;

            port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

            getDataPoint();    // called here for testing. Values successfully split
        }
        // gotta catch 'em all
        catch { stuff here }
    }

    private void getDataPoint()
    {
        /* still incomplete due to debugging phase */

        //
        //  Method for getting a data point from the Arduino unit
        //  Pings Arduino unit for a data point. Program then reads
        //  entire serial output until new line (\n) is found.
        //  Program splits the entire buffer in to the bufferArray
        //  and proceeds to distribute each element in to their
        //  respective Queues
        //

        buffer = "";
        bufferArray = new String[] { "" };
        tellArduino = "m";    // any random one-byte string to "ping" Arduino for a data point
                              // it |must| remain exactly one byte to avoid duplicate data

        port.Open();
        port.WriteLine(tellArduino);

        for (int x = 0; x < tellArduino.Length; x++)
        {
            buffer += port.ReadLine();
        }
        port.Close();

        // Split each value then add to respective queues
        bufferArray = buffer.Split(',');

        date.Enqueue(bufferArray[0]);
        time.Enqueue(bufferArray[1]);
        dcGen.Enqueue(double.Parse(bufferArray[2], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));


        // Start debugging code
        // adding to ListBox for debugging and checking reasons
        ports.BeginUpdate();
        foreach (String value in bufferArray)
        {
            ports.Items.Add(value);
        }
        // for testing type double printing
        ports.Items.Add(dcGen.ElementAt(0));
        //

        ports.EndUpdate();
        // End debugging code
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should try to open port once when you select port in the method **selectPort**, and closing port once when you close the application (form closing event).

Because port_DataReceived will trigger whenever it receive data, so you shouldn't put `port.Open();` in the method **getDataPoint.**

Comment: I think I misunderstood what I read somewhere. It goes like "Close the port as soon as you're done working with it." So, it actually means just opening it once, and then close it once and for all (for the duration of the program)?

Comment: Hi, In actually, the serial port should open and close once, during it's openning, you could read data any time you want and finally, close it. Have you tried my suggestion? Is this help?

Answer (score 0):

You are potentially executing getDataPoint() concurrently. The DataReceived will fire off your getDataPoint() but then you open and close the port. Just open the port once in select port and then close it when you exit the program or click "disconnect".

Answer (score 0):

I always insert this code immediately before instantiating or opening any serial port.  It also goes in my Form_Closing event handler.

```
if ((m_SerialPort != null)) {
    if (m_SerialPort.IsOpen) {
        m_SerialPort.Close();
    }
}
```

This is especially important if you have to stop debugging a program while the port is open.